# Git Update Submodule in main repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

The problem is that I can't apply changes made in my submodule to main repo. Steps:

1. I create main repo at github.
2. git clone [repo URL]
3. cd [main repo folder]
4. git submodule add [link to github submodule repo].
5. I use vscode to make small changes in my submodule repo. Everything stages and commits fine.

I can't find a way to synchronize it with my main repo.

Comment: Is the question about how to make Visual Studio do it, or is it about Git's submodules in general and how to do it from the command line where you've run commands 2, 3, and 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update --remote --recursive